# Docker how to allow traffic into tcp port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tcp

I have a docker container that is currently running on port 59521. When I inspect that container, I noticed that it has 4 ports:

- 443/tcp - localhost:59521
- 59521/tcp - 0.0.0.0:0
- 59522/tcp - 0.0.0.0:0
- 80/tcp - localhost:59522

However, on my latest container, this is what the 4 ports look like:

- 443/tcp - 0.0.0.0:59541
- 59541/tcp - 0.0.0.0:64064
- 59542/tcp - 0.0.0.0:64065
- 80/tcp - 0.0.0.0:59542

I am not able to connect to this container using Postman. I keep getting:

> Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection
> was established

How can I set it in my docker-compose or docker-compose.override file?

This is my docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  appone.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apponeapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: AppONE.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - ${NETWORK}
    ports:
    - "59541:443"
    - "59542:80"

networks:
  dev-network:
      name: ${NETWORK}
```

Comment: You set ASPNETCORE_URLS to port 443 and 80. Then you map port 443 to host port 59541. Is that the port you try to access it on? I.e. https://localhost:59541/

Comment: Hi @HansKilian yes. I want to access it on port 59541. So should I change the url port?